# Yup string length test validation with <= and not ===

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, react-hook-form, yup

I'm trying to check to see if a string is less than or equal to 30 characters with Yup and react-hook-form in TypeScript.

I've found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886881/validation-using-yup-to-check-string-or-number-length) on SO to check if a string length === 5 and it works great, with just the type of error handling messaging I'm looking for.

The cited example validation works as expected when applied in my schema

`title: Yup.string().test('len', 'Title must be exactly 5 characters', val => val?.length === 5).required('Title is required')`

But with a change for my case (checking to see if the string is less than or equal to 30) I get an `Object is possibly undefined` error, even though I believe th `?` should be covering the undefined case

`title: Yup.string().test('len', 'Title must be less than or equal to 30 characters', val => val?.length <= 30).required('Title is required')`

What's different between the use of `===` and `<=` in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `val` is `undefined`, the optional chain will automatically convert `val?.length` to `undefined` as well.

The equality operator `===` is meant to work will all types of values, including `undefined`, so even if you run `undefined === 15`, it will still be valid in TypeScript.

However, the greater than and less than operators such as `<=` are only meant to be used with `numbers`. If you try to do `undefined > 3`, TypeScript will give you an `Object is possibly undefined` error.